# How to scan Different QR code and list them In android

Tags: java, android-studio

I have to scan different qr code, and i want to scan one by one and differentiate them by count number, if the number has  12 number, then assign it `master` if the number is 10 assign as `slaves` and this slaves can be more than one but `master` is scan once.

So far i have done to scan one qr code, but if i scan the second one it delete that one.

WHat can i do to repeat scan and differentiate them.

My code:

```
public  void ScanButton(View view){
    IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    intentIntegrator.initiateScan();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(intentResult !=null){
        //kama imeshindwa kuscan then cancel
        if(intentResult.getContents() == null){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "TUnable to Scan, Please Make sure UnaScan QR Code",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            toast.show();
     //    textView.setText("Unable to Scan, Please Make sure UnaScan QR Code!");

        }
        else{
           textView.setText(intentResult.getContents());
        }
    }
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

am Expect to Have something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So an easy way to store the qr-code content would be to create an ArrayList to store the different scans.

```
ArrayList<String> qrScans = new ArrayList();
```

The could could then look something like this:

```
public  void ScanButton(View view){
    IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    intentIntegrator.initiateScan();

}

ArrayList<String> qrScans = new ArrayList();

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(intentResult !=null){
        //kama imeshindwa kuscan then cancel
        if(intentResult.getContents() == null){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "TUnable to Scan, Please Make sure UnaScan QR Code",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            toast.show();
     //    textView.setText("Unable to Scan, Please Make sure UnaScan QR Code!");

        }
        else{
           qrScans.add(intentResult.getContents());
           textView.setText(intentResult.getContents());
        }
    }
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This would also allow you to differentiate them, because they are stored in different indexes inside the ArrayList. Therefore you would be able to retrieve a very specific scan and can then operate on the content.

Comment: I have tested but does not appeared in arraylist what can we do to add the second scanned code when we intiate the camera

Comment: I mean the logic to save scan data in a list